# Жаренный без зависимого слова

Tags: прилагательные, причастия, суффиксы, нн

Немного душноты.

Слово **жареный** является отглагольным прилагательным. А **жаренный** — причастие несовершенного вида. Соответственно, словосочетание "жареная картошка" пишется с одной **Н**, а словосочетание "жаренная в масле картошка" — с двумя. Хоть и принято объяснять количество **Н** наличием зависимых слов, но это не совсем корректно, на мой взгляд. Зависимое слово лишь подсказывает: какую часть речи стоит употребить. А уже исходя из этого определяется количество **Н**.

Помогите составить пример, в котором слово "жаре**нн**ый" (или схожие по написанию слова) употреблялось бы в виде причастия, но без зависимых слов.

Comment: Что значит причастие несовершенного вида? Действие не закончилось, картошка жарится до сих пор?

Comment: @Sharon ну поправьте вопрос, если я ошибся

Comment: Посмотрите вариант правки. Если ПОДХОДИТ, то исправьте вопрос сами. Слово «жареный» является отглагольным прилагательным (одна буква Н). А какой частью речи является слово «жаренный» в словосочетании "жаренная в масле картошка" (две буквы НН). Хоть и принято объяснять…

Comment: @sharon Прежде чем писать сюда, я прогуглил. Гугл сказал, что "жаренный" причастие несовершенного вида. Да, я задумался: почему именно несовершенного. Но кто я такой, чтобы спорить с гуглом

Comment: Действительно, с гуглом не поспоришь...  Но вы-то нам скажите, как вы понимаете этот термин? Причастие - это форма глагола, а глагол несовершенного вида обозначает незаконченное действие.  Значит, причастие несовершенного вида тоже обозначает незаконченное действие? Просто поясните вашу точку зрения, если согласны с гуглом.

Comment: @sharon я не стал с ним спорить потому, что допускаю, что могу ошибиться. Я не лингвист. То, что мне кажется глупым может оказаться правдой. Кому верить в таком случае? Пользователям стэка? Но ведь когда-то и гугл выдавал "здешние" ответы на запрос.

Comment: Кому верить? Я думаю, что верить надо авторитетным источникам. Что касается пользователей стэка, то они должны доказывать свою точку зрения, давая ссылки на эти источники. Ну вот я даю ссылку на учебник на сайте Грамота.ру и привожу ниже цитату. При желании можно поискать более авторитетные источники, но я не уверена, что вам там встретится ваш термин. Впрочем, давайте оставим вопрос как он был и послушаем других участников. Могу только добавить, что это одна из самых спорных тем в грамматике и правописании. Поэтому быстрых ответов не приходится ждать, желающих будет скорее не так много.

Comment: 2. Слово в полной форме с суффиксом -н-(-нн-), -ен-(-енн)- является отглагольным прилагательным, если оно образовано от глагола НСВ и не имеет зависимых слов, и является причастием, если образовано от глагола СВ и/или имеет зависимые слова, ср.: некошеные луга (прилагательное), не кошенные косой луга (причастие, т.к. есть зависимое слово), скошенные луга (причастие, т.к. СВ). gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm

Comment: @Sharon чёт как-то странно выходит. Почему причастие непременно должно быть с зависимым словом, особенно если это слово очевидным образом подразумевается? Почему я не могу написать 'не кошенные луга', имея в виду 'не кошенные косой'? *Давно уже не кошенные жита и овсы* (Катаев).

Comment: Правилами орфографии такое написание не предусмотрено. И давайте не смешивать грамматику и правописание (выбор Н и НН). Если говорить о грамматике, от глаголов НСВ можно образовать прилагательное (одна Н, кошеный) и причастие (НН, виденный). Прилагательные обозначают постоянный признак, а причастие - признак, связанный со временем, так как время - основная категория глагола.   Некошеные луга - это заросшие травой (прилаг.) и к вашей косе отношения не имеют, то есть не имеют никакого отношения к действию.  А в прилагательных используется суффикс ЕН, его и пишите. Это –  грамматика,

Comment: А правописание  отражает грамматику в виде правил. Кошеный, некошеный –  постоянный качественный признак (прилаг.)  А что вы дополнительно подразумеваете, не имеет отношения ни к грамматике, ни к письму.

Comment: @Sharon честно говоря, я ничего не понял. Вот 'н/нн' и '"не" слитно/раздельно' — две темы, в которых я по сей день путаюсь, не улавливаю логики. Просто запоминаю частные случаи.

Comment: Статейку мою не хотите почитать (очень короткую).  Тоже не образец (я не особо ею довольна), но, может, что-то прояснит для вас. Путаная это тема... Иногда кажется, что лучше действительно просто запомнить правила https://proza.ru/2021/06/22/598

Comment: @Sharon почитаю, только завтра, на свежую голову :) Спасибо.

Comment: @sharon, благодарю. "Скошенные луга" исчерпывающий ответ. То что мне и нужно. К примеру, вырубленный лес тоже подходит, если я все понял

Comment: @Хацкер Причастия скошенный и вырубленный образованы от глаголов совершенного вида, поэтому это причастия, им зависимые слова для этого статуса не нужны. Приставка обычно меняет вид глагола.  Например, жареный – прилагательное (качественный признак), а пожаренный – причастие (завершенное действие).

Answer (score 1):

Не ищите — всё равно не найдёте такого.

Comment: Что вы скажите про "скошенные луга"? "Вырубленный лес"?

Comment: Причастия, образованные от глаголов совершенного вида, вполне могут быть и без зависимых слов.

Answer (score 1):

Выделенные цифры вставил я.

> Помогите составить пример, в котором слово "жаренный" (или схожие по
> написанию слова **1**) употреблялось бы в виде причастия **2**, но без
> зависимых слов **3**.

Пример.
Долго голодающему надо с осторожностью есть зажаренный лук.

1. Слова "жаренный" и "зажаренный" сходны по написанию.
2. "Зажаренный" причастие. Ограничений на вид причастия в вопросе нет.
3. Зависимых слов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Кто не любит картошку?! Но жаренная именно на подсолнечном масле вкуснее!

Comment: так всё равно есть же зависимое слово

Comment: @ЕленаСмагина Вкуснейшая штука ― рыба, *жаренная на рожне*, кто, конечно, умеет ее жарить, чтоб не сжечь хвоста и брюха, а спину рыбы не оставить сырой. [Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)] Мокрые и грязные, они шли после работы в столовую, где им давали эту же самую картошку: на первое ― густой картофельный суп, на второе ― картошка, *жаренная на маргарине*, который они привезли из Москвы. [Вадим Кожевников. Щит и меч. Книга первая (1968)] **Жаренный** (на чём?) на подсолнечном масле, на углях, на сковородке (на чём угодно) — есть зависимое слово, поэтому пишется -НН-.